# LINQ to SQL Unmapped Property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to add a custom property in the designer and have it not bound to a column?  I fiddled with the settings a bit settled on making a partial class with the property.  Is there a way to show this field in the ORM designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ-to-SQL designer is maintaining the mapping. Unmapped properties need to go in a separate partial class.

Answer (score 1):

In the Designer, right click on the Object Properties header and Add => Property.

Comment: This results in a SqlException: "Invalid column name {MyColumnName}"

Comment: whoops, forgot this: 

Add this attribute to the Property in the designer.cs file.
[Column(IsDbGenerated=false)]

Comment: You should probably just make this Property

public string PropertyName { get; set; }

you'll have to do this each time you rebuild your DBML, but you'll get the ORM Designer showing the Property like you wanted.

Comment: yeah I realized the attribute will be overwritten.  Looks like I will just use the partial class.